# Are esper time intervals supported in fiware perseo?

Tags: fiware, complex-event-processing, esper, fiware-perseo

I'm trying to model a rule for perseo CEP using esper time intervals (timer:interval), like the one documented on http://esper.espertech.com/release-6.1.0/esper-reference/html/event_patterns.html#pattern-atoms.

In particular this example which must be fire every 20 seconds is never executed:

```
{
    "name": "timer_interval_update",
    "text": "select *,\"timer_interval_update\" as ruleName from pattern [every timer:interval(20 sec)]",
    "action": {
        "type": "update",
        "parameters": {
            "id":"${id}",
            "type":"A",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "name": "status",
                    "value": "open",
                    "type": "text"
                }

            ]
        }
    }
}
```

In the perseo-core log I'm receiving:

```
time=2018-07-31T19:17:11.821Z | lvl=INFO | from= | corr=n/a | trans=n/a | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | op=update | comp=perseo-core | msg=rule fired: WrapperEventBean [event=MapEventBean eventType=com.espertech.esper.event.map.MapEventType@7c584419] [properties={ruleName=timer_interval_update}]
time=2018-07-31T19:17:11.827Z | lvl=ERROR | from= | corr=n/a | trans=n/a | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | op=DoHTTPPost | comp=perseo-core | msg=exception IOException: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
time=2018-07-31T19:17:11.828Z | lvl=ERROR | from= | corr=n/a | trans=n/a | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | op=update | comp=perseo-core | msg=action post failed
```

I'm using a dockerized environment using this docker-compose:

https://github.com/aguirrea/fiware-perseo-test.git